# "We" meaning a group of people that I am not talking to and myself

Tags: phrase-requests, clusivity

Is there a word or phrase to express the idea of a group of people and the speaker, collectively, where the group of people is explicitly *not* the people who are being spoken to?

For example, consider the hypothetical situation where I am a representative of a country and I wish to talk about my country by saying *we*, *us*, and *our*.  Also consider that I am talking to group of other country representatives (the U.N. would be a good example) and that I need to go back and forth from addressing the group to addressing my country as a group.  In this scenario, I wish to use non-ambiguous pronouns for my country.

Is there a word or phrase that can help express this idea?

Comment: English does not make the distinction. Native speakers are unaware there are two possible meanings, and figure out who's involved from context. Or else they don't.

Comment: @John: maybe I hang around relatively smart people, but I think most English speakers are aware of the ambiguity at some level; they'll sometimes say *"we—you and me— ..."* or *"we—the audience— ..."* in cases of possible ambiguity. (Although more often they leave it ambiguous.)

Comment: And most often we just figure it out; we're usually quite good on figuring out whether we're included in what the speaker is saying.

Comment: There is a line in a Judy Bloom novel along the lines of "We're going to the game." "We are?" "No, not *we*, *us*— Alex and I."

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599044/2085).

Answer (score 0):

To remove any uncertainty, you could say, "My countrymen and I," instead of *we*.